# How to specify working directory for sqlite3_open

Tags: xcode, sqlite

Working in xCode everything works OK if I execute by double-clicking the project down in the working directory but not from xCode itself doing a Build and Run. Then the database isn't being found correctly.

How do I modify...

```
 sqlite3_open("Airports.sqlite", &db);
```

so it can find Airports.sqlite in the current working directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy your database to your applications directory and after that you can use your database :)

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *dbPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Airports.sqlite"];

BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];

if (!succes){

    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Airports.sqlite"];
                BOOL success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:dbPath error:&error];

                if (!success) 
                    NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
                else
                    NSLog(@"Succesfully created writable database");
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  **Really sorry** but how would I do this in Ansi C?  I'm bootstrapping myself and starting with the basics before I take on Obj C and the Foundations.  I tried copy and paste manually, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @MonkeyBusiness okey.. I don't know how to do that in Ansi C. I've started with Obj C after PHP.

Comment: Success.  Never could move my original SQLite file down to the working director or get code to work, so I just renamed the file and started over.  The coding is easy compared to getting past all xCode's high-level "assistance."